# Image of a function containing a $\heartsuit$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the image of
$$f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N\cup\{\heartsuit\},m\mapsto\begin{cases}
2m+1&m>0\\
\heartsuit&m=0\\
-(2m-1)&m<0
\end{cases}$$
How do I approach this? I couldn't attend the lecture and cannot ask peers.

Comment: You have a function definition... but what is the task?

Comment: Sincerely, I didn't understand anything, expecially hearts...

Comment: I would say ♡ is some object other than a number.  Values of functions do not have to be numbers.

Comment: The heart is some object in this set. They use it frequently at my uni

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The image is the set of values within $\mathbb{N}\cup\heartsuit$ that the function reaches.

The function takes in values from $\mathbb{Z},$ the integers. So plug in $1, 2, 3,\dots$, and plug in $0$, and plug in $-1, -2, -3,\dots$.

Then make a guess for which values you could reach based on the patterns from the $1,2,3,\dots$ and the $-1,-2,-3,\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

From the declaration $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N\cup\{\heartsuit\}$ you know that the image $f(\mathbb Z)$ must be a subset of the set $\mathbb N\cup\{\heartsuit\}$.

I don't know what kind of mathematical object $\heartsuit$ is, but apparently it is something that can be a member of a set.

You also have a definition of $f$.

Try a few examples of $f(m)$ and see what the results are.
What are the values of $f(-2),$  $f(-1),$  $f(0),$  $f(1),$ and $f(2)$?
All of those values belong to the image $f(\mathbb Z)$.

Now you just need to cover all the other values of $f(m)$:
$f(3)$, $f(4),$ $f(5),$ and so forth,
as well as $f(-3)$, $f(-4),$ $f(-5),$ and so forth.